# Context menu does not work with Javascript generated HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to have a right-clickable link that shows a custom context menu. I am using [this](https://github.com/sydcanem/bootstrap-contextmenu) handy context menu plugin. I can get it to work for static HTML content, but when creating the html using javascript, the right clicking does not trigger my custom context menu. Does it have something to do with dynamically creating HTML?

My code to create the HTML is

```
$('.cmenu1content a').contextmenu();

$('#add_stuff').click(function () {
    var $html = '';
    $html += '<div class="cmenu1content"><a data-context-menu=".cmenu1" href="#">But this doesnt</a><ul class="context-menu dropdown-menu cmenu1"><li><a href="#" id="cetstart">Set Start Time</a></li> <li><a href="#" id="cetend">Set End Time</a></li><li><a href="#" id="cet5">Center time (5 min)</a></li><li><a href="#" id="cet30">Center time (30 min)</a></li><li><a href="#" id="cet60">Center time (60 min)</a></li><li><a href="#" id="cet360">Center time (6 hour)</a></li></ul></div>'
    $(".not_working_link").empty().html($html);
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle of my situation. The context menu plugin is from lines 1 - 75, but my code starts at line 77.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonk1993/a2WYS/

Comment: It's because the element you're adding in the click doesn't have the event handler. The simplest way is to add it when you add it in the `click` handler by calling `$('.not_working_link .cmenu1content a').contextmenu();`.

Comment: Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/a2WYS/6/ Note I changed it to `$html = $($html);` and used `$.append()` instead of `$.html()` so I can still reference it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can use a delegate pattern and work from a parent element (the `$.on()` method with the second argument selector), you should add the `$.contextmenu()` call within the `click` handler; otherwise, the event handler has not been set on the *new* element, only on the ones that existed when you ran the (previous) call.

```
$('#add_stuff').click(function () {
    // This will create a documentFragment that after appended, can
    // still be worked on, as you see on the third line below.
    var $html = $('<div class="cmenu1content"><a ... blah blah ... </div>');

    // Note the use of `$.append()` instead of `$.html()`.
    $(".not_working_link").empty().append($html);

    $html.children('.cmenu1content a').contextmenu();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a2WYS/7/

Comment: Thank you! This ending up fixing it!

Answer (score 0):

Use on http://api.jquery.com/on/ for making it works with generated elements or live in older jquery http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: The `$.contextmenu()` plugin actually has to be called, so not sure that using `$.on()` is the right approach.